# Emacs - define comments function

Tags: emacs

I am looking for an Emacs command to produce comments like the following :

```
;;===============================================
;; This is some text
```

Comment: Define it: `(defun foo () (interactive) (insert ";;====...\n") (insert ";; This...\n"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with wrap-region https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el

```el
;; example configuration
(require 'wrap-region)
(add-to-list 'wrap-region-except-modes 'web-mode)
(wrap-region-global-mode t)
(wrap-region-add-wrapper ";;========================================\n;; " "" "#" 'emacs-lisp-mode)
```

Then select the line you want to comment and `#`